# oracle error when second table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE faculty1(
f_num varchar2(5),
f_name varchar2(20),
rank varchar2(30),
d_name char(3),
salary number(8,2),
PRIMARY KEY(f_name)
);
```

Table created

```
CREATE TABLE class1(
c_name varchar2(10),
c_time varchar2(10),
f_name varchar2(20),
c_room varchar2(10),
semester varchar2(10),
PRIMARY KEY(c_name, c_time),
FOREIGN KEY(f_name) REFERENCES faculty1(f_name)
);
```

error at line 8

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE grade1(
s_name varchar2(10),
c_name varchar2(10),
grade char(1),
PRIMARY KEY(s_name,c_name),
FOREIGN KEY(c_name) REFERENCES class1(c_name)
);
```

same error as before

Comment: A foreign key should reference to a column with primary key.  f_name column in factulty1 table is not primary key.

Comment: `class1` has a composite primary key.  You need both keys in the reference.  By the way, you modified the question in such as way as to invalidate the answer by @notulysses.  This is impolite.  In the future, you should ask a separate question, because your original was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

`f_name` should be primary key in table `faculty1` to be referenced as a foreign key in `class1` table.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2876f)

Comment: can you show me by editing my code? I wanna see how it will look

Comment: @FrankBinder : Take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: Ok i did that now im getting another error, first 2 tables work.  3rd isnt.

Comment: look at the 3rd table i added at the top its getting the same error

Comment: @FrankBinder: The primary key of `class1` is  `PRIMARY KEY(c_name, c_time),` while you're trying to reference only `c_name` with `FOREIGN KEY(c_name) REFERENCES class1(c_name)` in `grade1`.[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e8cd)